# for loops is it possible to make multiple lines?

Tags: java

I need to make this figure, what is the best way to do this?

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~+~+~+~+~+~+~+~+~+~+~+~+~+~+~+~+~+~+~+~+~+~+~+~+
+~++~++~++~++~++~++~++~++~++~++~++~++~++~++~++~+
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I have made my code this way, is it correct? or could I make it a little more simple.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int line = 1; line <= 1; line++) {
        for (int star = 1; star <= 48; star++) {
            System.out.print("~");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
    for (int line = 1; line <= 1; line++) {
        for (int star = 1; star <= 24; star++) {
            System.out.print("~+");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
    for (int line = 1; line <= 1; line++) {
        for (int star = 1; star <= 16; star++) {
            System.out.print("+~+");
        }

        System.out.println();

    }
    for (int line = 1; line <= 1; line++) {
        for (int star = 1; star <= 48; star++) {
            System.out.print("~");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(int line = 1; line<=1; line++)` All of these are useless. They will run exactly once. Your code would be functionally equivalent if you removed all of these for statements. Aside from that, this looks like a good way to do it. I would only replace `24` with `48/2` and `16` with `48/3`. It makes it more clear what the numbers are for.

Comment: You can print these line using System.out.pringln("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ");

Comment: Lastly. This belongs on code review. Not Stackoverflow.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to CodeReview

Comment: You should also probably get in the habit of setting your for-loops to start at 0.  For instance, logically for (int star = 1; star <= 48; star++) is equal to for(int star = 0; star < 48, star++).  However once you learn about Arrays, these start their indexing (numbering scheme) at 0.  Getting in the habit of counting from 0 and starting most for-loops at 0 will make your life easier in the future.  (This is just a personal preference as a Java programmer, and will not increase your code performance at all.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this to reduce your line of codes .

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
           {
            method("~",48);
            method("~+",24);
            method("+~+",16);
            method("~",48);
                }
    public static void method(String a,int len){

         for(int star =1; star<=len; star++)
            {

                    System.out.print(a);
                }


            System.out.println();
         }
```

Comment: Why even leave the unnecesary loop the OP has?

Comment: Your formatting is also quite hard to follow (in my opinon).  Might make it easier for a new Java learner to follow if you selected a common brace style and indented appropriately.